# Scapy DNS answer rewrite adds extra bytes

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I am intercepting DNS responses and want to rewrite the answer fields to a different IP address to insert a proxy.

I am basically changing one IP address for another deep in the DNS data structure.
The program at the bottom actually demonstrates the behavior.

However, length of the dns packet before the operation is 401 and after the operation is 921.

The problem seems to start where a byte count (0x04) corresponding to mqtt gets replaced with 0xc0 (at the split in bytes [20:40] below)

Am I misusing scapy in some way?  Suggestions welcome.

```
    mismatch old: 401 new: 921
    dns1[0]: b'ac81818000010006000d0000046d7174740b7765'
    dns2[0]: b'ac81818000010006000d0000046d7174740b7765'
    dns1[20]: b'6174686572666c6f7703636f6d0000010001    c00c'
    dns2[20]: b'6174686572666c6f7703636f6d0000010001    046d'
    dns1[40]: b'00050001000000e4003c2177656174686572666c'
    dns2[40]: b'7174740b77656174686572666c6f7703636f6d00'
```

```
    import sys
    import binascii
    import scapy.all as scapy
    base_dns = """
    ac81818000010006000d0000046d7174740b77656174686572666c6f7703636f
    6d0000010001c00c00050001000000e4003c2177656174686572666c6f772d6d
    7174742d3930343536396236613839613961643503656c620975732d65617374
    2d3109616d617a6f6e617773c01dc032000100010000003c0004369cffb3c032
    000100010000003c0004365127ddc032000100010000003c00042cd9c48ec032
    000100010000003c0004035c8c32c032000100010000003c000422ee66660000
    02000100045d29001401620c726f6f742d73657276657273036e657400000002
    000100045d290004016bc0cb000002000100045d2900040166c0cb0000020001
    00045d2900040163c0cb000002000100045d2900040164c0cb00000200010004
    5d290004016cc0cb000002000100045d2900040165c0cb000002000100045d29
    0004016ac0cb000002000100045d2900040169c0cb000002000100045d290004
    016dc0cb000002000100045d2900040161c0cb000002000100045d2900040168
    c0cb000002000100045d2900040167c0cb
    """
```

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        dns_l = base_dns.split('\n')
        new_dns = ''.join(dns_l)
        dns_b = binascii.a2b_hex(new_dns)
        dns = scapy.DNS(dns_b)
        b_dns_1 = bytes(dns)
        dns_len_1 = len(b_dns_1)
        #print(dns.show(dump=True))
        dns.an[1].rdata = '10.135.0.1'
        b_dns_2 = bytes(dns)
        dns_len_2 = len(b_dns_2)
        #print(dns.show(dump=True))
        if dns_len_1 != dns_len_2:
            print('mismatch old: ' + str(dns_len_1) + ' new: ' + str(dns_len_2))
            for i in range(0, min(dns_len_1, dns_len_2), 20):
                print('dns1[' + str(i) + ']:', binascii.b2a_hex(b_dns_1[i:i+20]))
                print('dns2[' + str(i) + ']:', binascii.b2a_hex(b_dns_2[i:i+20]))
            sys.exit(1)
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that scapy keeps a cached version of the dns record in compressed form, but when it is modified, it is kept in an uncompressed form.

dns.compress() can be used to take the uncompressed packet and generate the compressed form.